# ajax tabs and event handling

Tags: c#, javascript

I have an app that contains a dropdownlist and tabs. What I what it to do is when I click on the tab, it should change the dropdownlist to relfect the active tab and visa-versa. I have tried javascript but since the ddl is on the server and javascript invokes from the client, it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

RV

Comment: If you post the scripts that you already have in place, it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample using asynchronous postbacks(set the TabContainer's and DropDownList's AutoPostback property to `true`):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdDdlTabs" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlTabs" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Tab1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Tab2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Tab3"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdTabContainer" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <ajax:tabcontainer ID="TabContainer1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" >
        <ajax:TabPanel HeaderText="Tab1" runat="server" ID="Tab1">
            <ContentTemplate>This is Tab1</ContentTemplate>
        </ajax:TabPanel>
        <ajax:TabPanel HeaderText="Tab2" runat="server" ID="Tab2">
            <ContentTemplate>This is Tab2</ContentTemplate>
        </ajax:TabPanel>
        <ajax:TabPanel HeaderText="Tab3" runat="server" ID="Tab3">
            <ContentTemplate>This is Tab3</ContentTemplate>
        </ajax:TabPanel>
     </ajax:tabcontainer>
</ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Codebehind (VB.NET, but the point should be clear):

```
Private Sub DdlTabs_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DdlTabs.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case DdlTabs.SelectedValue
        Case "Tab1"
            Me.TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 0
        Case "Tab2"
            Me.TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 1
        Case "Tab3"
            Me.TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 2
    End Select
    Me.UpdTabContainer.Update()
End Sub

Private Sub TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabContainer1.ActiveTabChanged
    Select Case TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex
        Case 0
            Me.DdlTabs.SelectedValue = "Tab1"
        Case 1
            Me.DdlTabs.SelectedValue = "Tab2"
        Case 2
            Me.DdlTabs.SelectedValue = "Tab3"
    End Select
    Me.UpdDdlTabs.Update()
End Sub
```